# Symfony (Doctrine) - leftJoin, OneToMany and result hierarchy

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a one-to-many relationship between a Post and a Comment.

Post: id, title

Comment: id, title, text, post_id

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->getRepository('MyBundle:Comment')->createQueryBuilder('comment');

$qb->select('comment, post')->leftJoin('comment.post', 'post');

$result = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();

return new JsonResponse($result);
```

I get this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Comment 1",
    "text": "Comment text 1",
    "post": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Post 1"
    }
  }
]
```

That's what I want:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Post 1",
    "comment": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Comment 1",
      "text": "Comment text 1"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You query Comment and add Post to comment, do the reverse, MyBundle:Post and query comments

Comment: Then I get the following: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 89 near 'comment': Error: Class Demo\MyBundle\Entity\Post has no association named comment

Comment: Does you relation is in the good way ? Post -> Comment and not Comment -> Post ? could you add your entities ? (Only the field where you do your relations)

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Provide definition of your entities